# Can't get wav files to play on iPad using Safari

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, wav

I have a web application that I have built and it needs to have three different kind of alerts. Single beep, long beep and triple beep. All the audio files are in .wav format. The application works as expected with all beep notifications playing at the right time on a Mac or PC, with IE, FireFox, Chrome and Safari on Mac.

When I run the application on an iPad it only wants to play the single beep and will play it every time it is supposed to. When it's supposed to play the long beep or triple beep, it doesn't.

Can somebody please tell me why this is happening and what I can do to get this working? This web application was built to run on the iPad and full web browsers. This is the last thing that needs to be worked out, before the application is completed.

Thanks in advance. :)

Here is my code for the audio tags and the javascript that makes it work.

**HTML**

```
    <span style="visibility:hidden; display: none; ">
        <audio src="./sounds/beep.wav"></audio>
        <audio src="./sounds/longBeep.wav"></audio>
        <audio src="./sounds/tripleBeep.wav"></audio>
    </span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function playBeep() {
        var beepAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        beepAudio.play();    
    }

    function playLongBeep() {
        var beepAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
        beepAudio.play();    
    }

    function playTripleBeep() {
        var beepAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];
        beepAudio.play();    
    }
```

All the audio files are using the same codec and the format.

[image]

Comment: Are the 3 .wavs using the same codec? Remember that .wav is a container format, and the audio data itself can use pretty much any codec under the sun. If the long/triple .wavs are using a codec the ipad doesn't support, then you will NEVER be able to get them to play.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using .wav files?

Comment: No I just need them to all play at this point.

Comment: Why not use MP3 instead? They are also way smaller than .wav files.

Comment: I have switched the files to .mp3, but still no luck. If I change the javascript for the longBeep and tripleBeep to be document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]; instead of 1 or 2... It plays the single beep everytime as expected. It's like its not loading the second audio element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [one audio tag at a time is supported on MobileSafari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10).

Use one audio element and change the src attribute using JS. Then call load/play when required. This is described in detail [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW5).

Comment: That just means that only one can be playing at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

IOS supports sound play, but not autoplay.  You must bring up a control that forces the user to hit a play button for the sound to start playing.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/